# Non-homeomorphicity of $\Bbb{N}$ and $\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n} | n\in \Bbb{N}\} \cup \Bbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology

The exercise asks to prove that any pair of three sets $$A=\Bbb{N}\\A'=\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n} | n\in \Bbb{N}\}\\
A''=\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n} | n\in \Bbb{N}\} \cup \Bbb{N}$$ is not homeomorphic.

I proved it for $(A,A'), \ (A',A'')$ using compactness of $A'$ and non compactness of the rest, but I struggle with proving the result for the pair $(A, A'')$.

The second part of the question asks to prove $A\times A'$ and $A' \times A''$ are homeomorphic.And with this part I also do have problems.

Comment: What is $i$? A fixed nonzero integer?

Comment: there should be 1 instead of i

Comment: thanks for your comment this was a typo I corrected it already

Comment: What topologies are at play here?

Comment: Hint: $A''$ contains an infinite compact subspace.

Comment: Like Jonathan said. Notice that compact sets in $A$ are finite

Comment: Or in other words, only one of them is discrete.

Comment: @Jonathan this is a subspace topology with topology inherited from standard topology of $\Bbb{R}$

Comment: @Jonathan Is this alrigt? let there exist homeo $f:A''\to A$ it is bijective from the definition, so it preserves cardinality then $[0,1]\cap A''$ must get mapped under $f$ to some subset of $A$ which is infinite, whats more $[0,1]\cap A''$ is compact and $f$ is continuous whence it would get mapped to a compact set in $A$, but there is no sets satisfying both of this conditions in $A$. Contradiction. So $f$ doesn't exist

Comment: what about the second part of the quesion

Comment: Every subset of $A$ is open. But $\{0\}$ is a non-open subset of $A''.$ So $A$ and $A''$ are not homeomorphic.

Comment: I don't think that $A\times A'$ and $A'\times A''$ can be homeomorphic. The set of accumulation points of $A\times A'$ is discrete, but the set of accumulation points of $A'\times A''$ is not discrete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A is discrete, not compact.  A' is compact, not discrete.
A" is not compact and not discrete.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that $f:A''\to A$ is a homeomorphism. Since $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ is a convergent sequence in $A''$ then $f(a_n)$ is convergent in $A$. But since $A$ is discrete then convergent sequences in $A$ are precisely sequences which are **eventually constant**. Meaning that $f(a_n)$ is an eventually constant sequence which is a contradiction because $f$ is injective.

> The second part of the question asks to prove $A\times A'$ and $A' \times A''$ are homeomorphic.And with this part I also do have problems.

Right, so this isn't true (thanks @JustinYoung). Every homeomorphism maps non-isolated points to non-isolated points. In particular if $A\times A'$ and $A'\times A''$ are homeomorphic then so are their respective sets of non-isolated points.

But a point in $A\times A'$ is non-isolated if and only if it is of the form $(n,0)$. Therefore the space of all non-isolated points of $A\times A'$ is discrete.

On the other hand the space of all non-isolated points of $A'\times A''$ has at least $(0,0)$ and $(0, \frac{1}{n})$. And thus it is not discrete.

Comment: It looks to me like $f: A\times A' \to A'\times A''$  is not surjective. For example, $(1/3,1/3)$ doesn't seem to be in the image.

Comment: @JustinYoung right, that was a wrong idea anyway. How about now?

Comment: $y\in A''$ need not be an integer.

Comment: @JustinYoung I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is true:

> if X,Y are homeomorphic topological spaces, with homeomorphism h:X$\rightarrow$Y, and if z $\in$ X is a limit point of X, then h(z) is a limit point for Y.

Since 0 is a limit point for A'', but it is not a limit point for A, then A and A'' are not homeomorphic.

It has been several years since I studied math, so excuse me if I am incorrect.

Comment: Not quite. A homeomorphism need not map $0$ to $0$. For example $A=\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is homeomorphic to $B=\{a-1\ |\ a\in A\}$ even though $0$ is not a limit point in $B$. The homeomorphism is given by $x\mapsto x-1$. But you were on the right track: see my answer.

Comment: Ah, yes, it is not necessary that $h(0)$$\rightarrow$ $0$.  Thanks for the correction @freakish